# CSS menu overlapping another menu

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am using Wordpress for my website and in one of the template files i have added my own menu (see fiddle)

https://jsfiddle.net/bxdm4kye/

I am having an issue with the main wordpress menu now which overlaps my menu. If you take a look at this screen shot (https://s13.postimg.org/e1v9vqp2v/Screen_Shot_2016_09_12_at_18_04_04.png) you can see the WP menu is displaying a line through the dropdowns however this stops when i remove my menu

I added `z-index:999` to `#menu-product-categories > li {` on my menu as before i added this i could not hover or select the elements in my menu

how can i now prevent the line from display in the WP menu dropdown?

Comment: Try adding `z-index:9999` to your dropdown `ul`.

Comment: add this to which menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution. Please change the colors like you want to have. Hover the Switches item to see the effect.

See also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bxdm4kye/1/)

```css
.menu-product-categories-container {
 display:block;
 width:100%;
 height:60px;
 background:#F36F25;
}
#menu-product-categories {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 text-align:center;
 height:100%;
    z-index: 0;
}
#menu-product-categories > li {
 display: inline-block;
 z-index:9999;
    position:relative;
 padding:21px 8px;
  text-decoration:none;
}
#menu-product-categories li > a {
    display: block;
    color:#F36F25;
}
#menu-product-categories > li:hover {
 background:#FFFFFF;
 color:#F36F25;
}
#menu-product-categories > li > a:hover {
 color:inherit;
}
#menu-product-categories ul.sub-menu {
    list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 text-align:center;
 display:none;
 width:200px;
 position:absolute;
 z-index:1;
 left:0;
 top:40px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
}
#menu-product-categories li:hover ul.sub-menu {
 display: block;
 max-height: 200px;
 background: #FFFFFF;
}
#menu-product-categories ul.sub-menu li {
 color:#FFFFFF;
 padding:5px;
}
#menu-product-categories ul.sub-menu li:hover {
 color:#F36F25;
 background:#000000;
 float:none;
 padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-product-categories-container">
<ul id="menu-product-categories" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-2933" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat current-menu-item menu-item-2933"><a href="/shop/product-category/desk-phones/">Desk Phones</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-2934" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-2934"><a href="/shop/product-category/headsets/">Headsets</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-2931" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-2931"><a href="/shop/product-category/conference-phones/">Conference Phones</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-2932" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-2932"><a href="/shop/product-category/dect-phones/">Dect Phones</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-2935" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-2935"><a href="/shop/product-category/routers/">Routers</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-2936" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-2936"><a href="/shop/product-category/switches/">Switches</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Dropdown 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Dropdown 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Dropdown 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Dropdown 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-2930" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-2930"><a href="/shop/product-category/cctv/">CCTV</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: brilliant thank you